# Hypercube perfect matchings

Tags: graph-theory

I want to know how to prove that the number of perfect matchings for $Q_n$ is greater than or equal $2^{2^{n-2}}$.
I tried to prove this with induction.

We know that it works for $Q_2$.
So we can assume that it works for $\leq n$ and we show that it works for $n+1$.
I know that we can represent each vertex of a hypercube as binary strings of length $n$.
So I wanted to show that if we have $Q_{n+1}$ that we have $2^{2^{n-2}}$ $Q_n$ in $Q_{n+1}$

But I don't see exactly how to show that. I tried something with conversion from $n$-binary to $(n+1)$-binary. So I would be glad if someone told me how could make this solution work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An $n+1$-dimensional hypercube decomposes into two $n$-dimensional hypercubes. If we know that an $n$-dimensional hypercube has more than $2^{2^{n-2}}$ perfect matchings, then pick a matching in each independently and find at least $(2^{2^{n-2}})^2$ perfect matchings in an $n+1$-dimensional hypercube.

Comment: Thx. now i knew where i made mistake.

Comment: Is there a way to calculate total number of perfect matching for an n-dimensional Hypercube?